# The Best Way To Code An Order Form

Tags: php, javascript

[image: Print Order Form]

I am looking to set up this order form on my website for ordering Printing Packages. All its required to do is add up the total price for the customer and send the order in an email to our Printer. No invoicing or checkout required.

What would be the best way to approach this to avoid complexity? Javascript? Or is there another language/tools that would be better suited?

The website is written in php.

Comment: Unrelated question. What did you use to generate that image?

Comment: The original design was done in Pages (Mac) and I just used a screenshot and saved it as a .jpg :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as updating the pricing columns you'll want to do that in javascript. A quick google search found [this](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-151850.html) forum thread about updating price columns.

After Send though you should verify all line items and pricing server side with php to verify that price total is sane. You'll need to send the email via PHP as well. Theres numerous pear modules for sending mail.

I like to use Smarty to templatize any emails I'm sending. This is up to you though.

Comment: Thanks for your advice on this one - I'll follow your suggestion!